# Consulta no me devuelve ningún dato

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Al hacer la siguiente consulta tengo el problema de que la base de datos me dice que esa query no devuelve ningún dato, pero estoy seguro de que si lo devuelve por que me he asegurado de que está.

```
$consulta = $con->prepare("select id_municipio from municipios where   nombre like :nombre");
$consulta->bindParam(':nombre',$columnas[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultado = $consulta -> execute();
$cuenta = $consulta->rowCount();
```

Tengo la clase PDO incluida, así que no tengo ningún problema con la consulta. Lo que me sucede es que la base de datos no me devuelve ningún dato y me debería de devolver 1 línea.

He intentado averiguar si es el último espacio el que da el problema y he añadido la siguiente linea de código para ver que ocurre.

```
echo "->".$columnas[$i]."<-";
```

Se que es un poco 'chapuza' pero al mostrarlo por pantalla me muestra esto:

```
->Madrid <-
```

Es ese último espacio el que me da problemas y no consigo quitarlo con ningun metodo(trim,substr...).

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer `'%'. $columnas[$i] .'%'`en el `bindParam`? Sin eso el `like` es igual a hacer un `=`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rapidez Alvaro. Si lo he probado y aun asi me sigue dando el mismo error, como si la base de datos no tuviera nada.

Comment: Porque no intentas con `$consulta->bindValue()` a ver si te funciona. Creo que hay algunas limitaciones con `bindParam()`

Comment: @Adrian no deberias usar bindParam, tal como dice Kenny Barrera es mejor bindValue y creo que el problema podria estar en el like, ya que leyendo la guia de PDO de phpdelusion dice que no se puede pasar asi una variable en el condicional like

Comment: Ya he cambiado el codigo poniendo bindValue. ¿Cual seria la mejor manera de poner el 'like'?¿debería de usar '='?

Comment: Señores, PDO es más simple de como lo imaginamos, no se necesita ni `bindParam` ni `bindValue` (ver respuesta mía más abajo y al final de la misma un demo funcionando con datos reales).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que puedo observar, me parece que NO devuelve datos porque estas asignando incorrectamente la variable que se usara en el condicional `like`.

**Cito:**

> Si, he probado a poner `$consulta->bindParam(':nombre',"Madrid",PDO::PARAM_STR);` y la base de datos me devuelve los datos correctamente, quiero decir que la consulta está bien hecha y no da ningun fallo.

**¿Y porque pasa esto?**, porque **ÚNICAMENTE** puedes asignar a sentencias preparadas: `string` y `números`, siendo los `strings` valores literales **entrecomillados**.

No puedes asignar nada mas, en este caso nuestro condicional `%`, no funcionaria, al igual que no podríamos asignar un nombre a una tabla por sentencias preparadas.

Por lo tanto, para que funcione el condicional `like` debemos construir un **literal entrecomillado** para asignarlo a la sentencia cuando usemos el `bind()`.

**Nota:**

> Recomiendo usar `bindValue()` porque asigna el **valor** de la variable, a diferencia de `bindParam()` que asigna una referencia de la variable, esto quiere decir que:
>
> ```
> $ejemplo "hola";
> bindParam("ejemplo",$ejemplo,PARAM::PDO_STR)
> $ejemplo = 52525;
> ```
>
> La sentencia fallara porque como tenemos es una referencia de `$ejemplo` al cambiar el valor de la variable cambiara también el valor asignado a la
>   sentencia, ahora veamos `bindValue()`.
>
> ```
> $ejemplo "hola";
> bindValue("ejemplo",$ejemplo,PARAM::PDO_STR)
> $ejemplo = 52525;
> ```
>
> En este caso, funcionaria bien nuestra consulta, ya que, se paso el
>   valor "hola" y no la referencia a la variable.

---

## LIKE

Sigamos con nuestro problema, vamos a construir el literal entrecomillado que necesitamos,esto lo puedes hacer de tres maneras usando sentencias preparadas:

**Metodo 1**:

Pasamos los operadores de `like` junto al marcador de posiciones:

```
$variableCondicional = "a%";
$consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo LIKE '%?%'");
$consulta->bindValue(1,$variableCondicional,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$datos = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

**Metodo 2**:

Pasamos los operadores de `like` junto a la variable, reasignando su valor:

```
$busqueda = "a%";
$busqueda = "%$busqueda%";
$consulta  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE nombre LIKE ?");
$consulta->bindValue(1, $busqueda, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->execute()
$datos = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

**Método 3**:

Pasando directamente el valor en forma de literal entrecomillado:

```
$consulta = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE campo LIKE ?');
$consulta->execute(array('a%'));
```

---

Si publicas el código podríamos modificar el bucle, reasignando algo asi:

```
$columnas[$i] = "%$columnas[$i]%";
```

Luego asignándolo directamente a la consulta.

---

## ESPACIOS EN BLANCO

Ahora veamos el caso del valor con el espacio en blanco, **cambiemos el espacio en blanco por un guion bajo** para visualizarlo mejor:

```
$consulta[$i] = "Madrid_";
```

Podemos utilizar tres métodos para eliminar los espacios en blanco:

**Método 1**:

Usamos `trim()` para eliminar espacios en blanco en principio y final de la cadena:

```
$consulta[$i] = "Madrid_";
$variable = trim($consulta[$i]);
echo $variable; // "Madrid"
```

**Metodo 2**:
Usando rtrim(), con esto borraremos el espacio al final de la cadena:

```
$consulta[$i] = "Madrid_";
$variable = rtrim($consulta[$i]);
echo $variable; // "Madrid"
```

**Metodo 3**:
Usando `str_replace()`, para reemplazar los espacios.

```
$consulta[$i] = "Madrid_";
$variable = str_replace(" ","",$consulta[$i]);
echo $variable; // "Madrid"
```

---

## Método completo

Podríamos entonces definir algo así:

```
$busqueda = $columnas[$i];
$busqueda = trim($busqueda);
$busqueda = "%$busqueda%";
$consulta  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE nombre LIKE ?");
$consulta->bindValue(1, $busqueda, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$consulta->execute()
$datos = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que me quieres decir, pero no puedo poner una variable literal y entrecomillarla, por el la variable que uso la saco de un archivo .txt. Cuando saco las variables de este .txt, las uso bien y no me da problema, el problema me viene al usar la ultima variable de la fila, por que me añade un espacio al final y es ese espacio el que me da error en la base de datos. No se si me he explicado bien.

Comment: @Adrian hermano ya modifique la respuesta, revisa lo ultimo que agregue

Comment: El metodo rtrim no lo había probado y funciona a la perfección, me has salvado hermano. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @Adrian tranquilo, cualquier otra duda, nombrarme en un comentario de tu pregunta y te ayudare con gusto.

Answer (score 1):

El uso de PDO es más fácil de como uno se lo plantea, en muchos casos.

Tienes que tomar en cuenta lo siguiente:

Un marcador de posición tiene que representar un literal completo de datos solamente - una cadena o un número -. De ninguna manera puede representar una parte literal de una cadena o algo arbitrario de SQL. Por lo tanto, al trabajar con `LIKE`, **tienes que preparar tu literal completo primero, y luego enviarlo a la consulta de la manera habitual**:

```
$buscar = "%$columnas[$i]%"; //Te toca asegurar que la variable no tiene espacios sobrando, eso es asunto tuyo
$consulta = $con->prepare("select id_municipio from municipios where   nombre like ?");
$consulta->execute([$buscar]);
$cuenta = $consulta->rowCount();
```

Si como dices tienes que limpiar tu variable `$columnas[$i]` de espacios o datos sobrantes, ese asunto tuyo.

No veo por qué tienes que complicarte la vida con `bindParam`, `bindValue`... PDO es más simple de como lo imaginamos.

P. D.: Si quieres usarlo con marcadores de nombre:

```
$buscar = "%$columnas[$i]%"; //Te toca asegurar que la variable no tiene espacios sobrando, eso es asunto tuyo
$consulta = $con->prepare("select id_municipio from municipios where   nombre like :nombre");
$consulta->execute(["nombre:"=>$buscar]);
$cuenta = $consulta->rowCount();
```

### <kbd>[DEMO DE LO AFIRMADO EN ESTA RESPUESTA FUNCIONANDO CON DATOS REALES](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ch8k-8z3f)</kbd>

Comment: Agradecería un comentario sobre el por qué del -1, no lo considero justo, pues he aportado  una respuesta que simplifica el código y resileve el problema, además con ejemplo demostrable (ver enlace al final).

Comment: Es mi culpa, pulse sin querer el negativo y era positivo :), no me habia dado cuenta de ello

Comment: Agrega tambien solucion a la principal causa del problema, los espacios en blancos, porque la consulta dice que le funciona :)

Answer (score 0):

¿Estás haciendo esa consulta en un ciclo? porque veo que tienes la variable $i, si es así, no funciona porque bindParam necesita una variable por referencia.

Aquí lo dice en la documentación: [PHP Doc: val by reference](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php#98145)

No estoy muy seguro si es tu caso porque necesitaría ver un poco más de código, pero puedes probar también creando una variable $nombre = $columnas[$i] y pasarla al método bindParam.

Comment: Si, estoy usando un bucle para agregar ese parametro, ya lo he hecho anteriormente y no me ha dado problema alguno. Pero si me dices que es mejor hacerlo así, lo cambiare. Pero eso sigue sin solventar mi problema.

Comment: Viendo tu actualización, ¿estás seguro que es un string con el texto Madrid? 
¿Si en la consulta le cambias la variable al texto te da resultados?

`$consulta->bindParam(':nombre',"Madrid",PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Igual podrías hacer un debug con vardump para ver qué tiene exactamente esa variable.

Comment: Si, he probado a poner $consulta->bindParam(':nombre',"Madrid",PDO::PARAM_STR); y la base de datos me devuelve los datos correctamente, quiero decir que la consulta está bien hecha y no da ningun fallo.